# Как добавить сертификаты в REST запрос в RestAssured?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, certificate

Сейчас для отправки запроса использую springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient, подключаю клиентские ключ и сертификат (client.pem, client.key), корневой сертификат (root.pem) - всё работает.
В проекте везде используется RestAssured.
Как эти сертификаты и ключ добавить при отправки запроса через RestAssured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через keytool сгенерировал хранилище:

```
keytool -importcert -alias trustme -file root.pem -keystore cacerts
Enter keystore password:
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

Затем сгенерировал .jks:

```
keytool -import -file client.pem -alias example -keystore keystore.jks
```

И добавил в конфиги RestAssured:

```
RestAssured.config()
.sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig()
                .allowAllHostnames()
                .keyStore("src/test/certs/keystore.jks", "123456")
                .trustStore("src/test/certs/cacerts", "123456"));
```